# Created file has nothing in it

Tags: c, arrays, struct, fwrite

So I am suppose to make my program be persistent when opened and closed I assume I have to do this with a file, the program is a payroll program that uses structs.  2 Questions here 1. When it comes to this type would binary files be easier? I hear txt files are complicated but not sure why.
2. Here is my code it runs without error but when I go to the file nothing is written inside. These are my two structs

```
typedef struct{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
}DATE;

typedef struct{
    char name[100];
    int age;
    float hrsWorked;
    float hrlyWage;
    float regPay;
    float otPay;
    float totalPay;
    DATE payDate;

}PAYROLL;
```

and the code

```
void backUp(PAYROLL employee[], long int *pCounter)
{
    FILE *record = fopen_s(&record, "c:\\record.bin", "wb");
    if (record != NULL){
        fwrite(employee, sizeof(PAYROLL), 1, record);
        fclose(record);
    }
```

employee has stuff in its structs so I know its not empty if some one could explain the parameters for fwrite that'd be great!

Comment: Be careful!  Opening a file using `fopen` with mode "w" truncates the file to zero bytes, erasing whatever was previously in record.bin.  Make sure that is what you want.

Comment: Note that writing out (and reading in) raw structures this way is not very portable between different kinds of platforms and possibly even different compilers on the same platform (e.g. - that might decide int is differently sized).

Comment: @jschultz410 I see well I guess the last thing would be if I want the file to not truncate to 0 do what read command would I use? Would it be ab+ (want to be able to store then read it in to continue then store more data in the file and so on since the array is 1mill

Comment: You'd use "a+b" if you want to append new data to end, not ever erase anything and be able to read.  Otherwise, you'd use "r+b" if you wanted to be able to read and possibly overwrite or add onto the end of the file.

Comment: @jschultz410 Well I did this 
        `FILE *record;
 errno_t result = fopen_s(&record, "c:\\record.bin", "r+b");
 if (record != 0)
 {
  fread(employee, sizeof(PAYROLL), 1, record);
  fclose(record);
 }`
It compiles but then no data is actually loaded into my array.

Comment: First, ensure that the file is not empty through the OS.  Second, check that `result` is zero for success.  Third, check that the return value of `fread`, which reports how many items were read, equals `sizeof(PAYROLL)`.  Finally, your code only tries to read in one employee, not multiple.  To read multiple you either need to call `fread(employee, num_employees * sizeof(PAYROLL), 1, record);` or put the `fread` in a loop.  You could also call it differently: `fread(employee, num_employees, sizeof(PAYROLL), record);` then its return code indicates how many employees it successfully read in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up the usage of the longtime-standard `fopen()` function with the usage of the new-in-C11 `fopen_s()` function.  The latter returns an error code, not a stream pointer.  You are overwriting the stream pointer it sets via the first argument with that error code.

If the program successfully opens the file, it returns `0`.  After setting that as the value of `record`, `record` compares equal to `NULL` (in Microsoft's C implementation), so you don't even attempt to write.  If you caught that case and printed a diagnostic, then you would have had a clue (albeit a misleading one).

You should do this:

```
void backUp(PAYROLL employee[], long int *pCounter)
{
    FILE *record;
    errno_t result = fopen_s(&record, "c:\\record.bin", "wb");

    if (result == 0) {
        fwrite(employee, sizeof(PAYROLL), 1, record);
        fclose(record);
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: that fixed the problem, thanks! would binary be easier for an assignment like this? I tried txt to see if it would fix the problem to and it did write to the file but it the txt on the file were weird characters

Comment: @Jude: I'd use binary mode, although It shouldn't matter because you are using fwrite (and presumably fread).  It might matter if you use fprintf(record, "Hello world!\n"); because the \n may be converted to a multi-byte line terminator on Windoze, for example.

Comment: @jschultz410, yes, I think you're right about `record` comparing equal to `NULL`.  I have updated the answer with that explanation.

Comment: Thanks, @jschultz410, I have edited the answer to properly attribute `fopen_s()` to C11.